# Java actionPerformed questions

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, action

Hello everyone I am new to java programming and I begin to fell in love with making simple JPanel or JFrame games. But recently I'm starting to challenge myself on writing a more complicated game called "Doodle jump". As most of you may already heard of this game you are a object constantly jumping up to the next platform and if you fall then the game ends. I've made the platform and made it move up or down based on if the jumper falls or jumps up (if the object/jumper jumps up the platform moves down, if the object/jumper falls then the platform moves up and finally if the jumper falls all the way down then the game ends by showing you a "You lost" message, I also made it that if you click the space bar the object jumps and the "A" and "D" button to move the object/jumper to the right or left.). After getting all those working all i need is to make the jumper stop falling when it lands on a platform. I have no idea on how to make it work, I tried searching it up on the internet but the results are useless. I have no choice but to post this question up on stackoverflow.

If you want to take a look at my code then it is down below:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;
public class DoodleJump extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener{
static JFrame f; 
static int width=1200, height=930;
static int DoodleW=500, DoodleH=500;
static int DoodleW1=540, DoodleH1=530;
static int DoodleW2=500, DoodleH2=530;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth=200, DoodlePlatformHeight=400;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth1=400, DoodlePlatformHeight1=530;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth2=900, DoodlePlatformHeight2=874;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth3=345, DoodlePlatformHeight3=643;
static int DoodlePlatformWidth4=711, DoodlePlatformHeight4=957;
static boolean rightjumper,leftjumper;
static boolean jumper;
static boolean gameplay=true;
public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(DoodlePlatformWidth, DoodlePlatformHeight,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth1, DoodlePlatformHeight1,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth2, DoodlePlatformHeight2,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth3, DoodlePlatformHeight3,200,30);
    g.fillRect( DoodlePlatformWidth4, DoodlePlatformHeight4,200,30);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(DoodleW, DoodleH,50,50);
    g.fillRect(DoodleW1, DoodleH1,10,50);
    g.fillRect(DoodleW2, DoodleH2,10,50);
    if (gameplay==false){
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Rosewood Std Regular", Font.PLAIN, 100)); 
        g.drawString("You Lost",200,110);
        f.setBackground(Color.black);  
    }
}
public static void main(String a[]){
    DoodleJump D = new DoodleJump();
    f = new JFrame();
    D.init();       
    f.add(D);
    f.setSize(width,height);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.repaint();                      
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Timer t=new Timer(10,D);        
    t.start();                      
} 
public void init (){
    this.addKeyListener(this);  
    setFocusable(true);  
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (gameplay==true){
        if (jumper==true){
            DoodlePlatformHeight=DoodlePlatformHeight+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight1=DoodlePlatformHeight1+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight2=DoodlePlatformHeight2+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight3=DoodlePlatformHeight3+20;
            DoodlePlatformHeight4=DoodlePlatformHeight4+20;

        }
        if (jumper==false){
            DoodlePlatformHeight=DoodlePlatformHeight-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight1=DoodlePlatformHeight1-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight2=DoodlePlatformHeight2-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight3=DoodlePlatformHeight3-10;
            DoodlePlatformHeight4=DoodlePlatformHeight4-10;

        }
        if (leftjumper==true){
            DoodleW=(DoodleW-15);
            DoodleW1=(DoodleW1-15);
            DoodleW2=(DoodleW2-15);
        }
        if (rightjumper==true){
            DoodleW=(DoodleW+15);
            DoodleW1=(DoodleW1+15);
            DoodleW2=(DoodleW2+15);
        }

        if (DoodlePlatformHeight>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight1>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth1=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight1=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight2>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth2=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight2=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight3>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth3=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight3=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight4>height){
            DoodlePlatformWidth4=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*1201);
            DoodlePlatformHeight4=0;
        }
        if (DoodlePlatformHeight<0&&DoodlePlatformHeight2<0&&DoodlePlatformHeight3<0&&
                DoodlePlatformHeight4<0){
            gameplay=false;
        }
        f.repaint();
    }
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        jumper=true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        leftjumper=true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
        rightjumper=true;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        jumper=false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A){
        leftjumper=false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D){
        rightjumper=false;
    }
}
}
```

It'll be awesome if someone could help me out. Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is to check intersection of 2 objects (Shapes).

The platform is not moved and has a fixed Shape - Rectangle (let's name it platformRect). Jump object is moved (down) and also has a Shape - let's say Ellipse (and call it movingEllipse).

By Timer we change y coordinate of the movingEllipse (the ellipse is moved down). W have to detect collision.

You can use Shape class' method `public boolean intersects(Rectangle2D r)`

For the new Ellipse position you check whether it's intersects the platformRect. If no continue the moving down (decrease Y), if yes (platform below) stop the Y updating.